# Python socket over internet are not received

Tags: python, sockets, server, udp, client

My problem is that my server.py doesn't receive datas from the client.py over internet.

Client.py :

```
import socket
import time
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

UDP_IP = "myip"
UDP_PORT = 5001

count = 0
start = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

finish2 = 0
start2 = 0
while count < 1000:
    msg = str(count)
    count+=1
    sock.sendto(msg.encode("utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    data = sock.recv(3000)
    if(data.decode("utf-8") == "1"):
        start2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    elif(data.decode("utf-8") == "14999"):
        finish2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    print(data)
    print(finish2 - start2)

finish = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print(finish - start)
i = input("")
```

And the Server.py

```
import socket
import time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.68"
UDP_PORT = 5001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
start = 0
finish = 0
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if(data.decode("utf-8") == "1"):
        start = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    elif(data.decode("utf-8") == "14999"):
        finish = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        print (finish-start)
    print (data, addr)
    sock.sendto(data, addr)

i = input("")
```

My rooter is opened with external and internal port = 5001.
I don't understand what i forgot.
PS : There is a timer, it's just to see how many time it needs to send and receive 15000 datas with UDP over internet.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a simpler code just to establish the connection.

Simple `echo` server with hardcoded value, single send, single receive. On the server side print the `addr` got from `recvfrom`.

On the server side verify that the socket is correctly binded `netstat -pnlt | grep 5001` and verify the firewall let you in `iptables -L INPUT | grep 5001`, on the client side verify the port is accessible `nmap -sU -p 5001 <server address>`. The commands are for linux, google is your friend if your server/client is running on windows

-1 for over complicated example, you have network issues, not "how to do an udp speedtest" issue.

Comment: I simplified the code, now it's just a single send and a single receive but it doesn't work yet. The socket is correctly binded. The port is accessible and the firewall is technically ok. On localhost it works...

Comment: Have you tried to nmap the port ? Is your connection nated ? Do you do port forwarding (with udp protocol on the correct port obviously) ?